# Using preg_replace and RegEx to shorten URLs in a specific way

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

In order to shorten URLs and make them into links, I've been using

```
$url = '|((https?:\/\/)?([\d\w\.-]+\.[\w\.]{2,6})[^\s\]\[\<\>]*\/?[^\.\s])|i ';
$replace_url = '<a href="$1" target="_blank" title="$1">$3</a>';
$message = preg_replace($url, $replace_url, $message);
```

This turns a URL entered as `"https://www.google.com/#q=regex+usage&"` into a link that just shows the text as `"www.google.com"`.

Even though the full link text shows when hovered over, this doesn't help mobile users who would like to see more text showing what they're about to click on. I'd like to modify the regex so that its displays the link with this format `"www.google.com/#q...ge&"` where there are a couple characters after the `.com/` (if the `/` exists), and a few characters at the very end of the string.

So far I'm having no luck getting this to work. Any guidance would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Could you please let know what is the expected output for `"https://www.google.com/#q=regex+usage&"`?

Comment: Please check if [this demo](http://ideone.com/rkTkv4) works for you.